# Are Demons and Half-Fiends considered Evil Outsiders for Favored Enemy?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters

Favored Enemy: Outsider(evil) is slightly confusing to me personally because when you look under [fiends](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Fiend) and [demons](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Demon_Subtype) the succubus is under both. Which demon is under outsider(evil) is this an exception or are fiends technically demons at least under the benefit of favored enemy, or vice versa?
If they count as demons do half-fiends as well?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image: Venn diagram]

**Demons are a subset of fiends.**

All evil outsiders are fiends. Chaotic evil fiends are demons.

Having evil outsiders as your favored enemy means you get the bonus against all fiends and all demons (because fiends == evil outsiders, and demons are a type of fiend).

The half-fiend template changes the target creature's type to outsider, but does not appear to give it the evil subtype, so you most likely would *not* receive your favored enemy bonus against a half-fiend.

Comment: IIRC, you cannot chose demons as your favoured enemy, but rather Outsider (Evil).

Comment: i corrected my self in the comment's to the question and about to fix it for the question it's self

Comment: It's worth mentioning that Half-Fiend is a template that makes the character change its type to Outsider. They count as evil outsiders for the purpose of Favored Enemy bonus.

Comment: if you add that as an answer it's what i'm primarily looking for i just worded the question awkwardly. i just used it to clarify differences as well.

Comment: also oblivion sage thank you for the clarification. :)

Comment: @MrLemon Fighting one fiery, evil, extraplanar thing tends to help fighting others! Also, one version of Asmodeus' background lore includes him creating the Devils by fighting the Demons until he and his group became like them.

Comment: Wait... the half-fiend page says that the _alignment_ is always evil, but not that it adds the evil _subtype_. Also, does it add e.g. the chaotic subtype for a half-demon?

Answer (score 4):

All monsters have a Creature Type, which can be found near the top of the stat block. Some types, such as *Humanoid* and *Outsider*, always have a subtype as well, indicated in (parenthesis).

"Fiend" is a flavor term used to describe a multitude of alignment-evil *Outsiders*, not all of which have the (*Evil*) subtype; a specific example being the Rakshasa, which is of the *Outsider* (*Native*) type.

Favored Enemy selections indicate which Creature Type the Ranger receives bonuses against. Only those monsters with that specific type (subtype) count.

The Half-Fiend template changes the creature's type to *Outsider,* and its alignment to "always evil."

However, from page 291 of the Monster Manual 3.5, under Templates:

> If a template changes the base creature’s type, the creature also
>   acquires the augmented subtype (see page 306) unless the template description indicates otherwise. The augmented subtype is
>   always paired with the creature’s original type. For example, a unicorn with the half-celestial template is an outsider with the augmented magical beast subtype.

Then, from page 140, under Half-Fiend:

> Size and Type: The creature’s type changes to outsider. Do not
>   recalculate Hit Dice, base attack bonus, or saves. Size is unchanged. Half-fiends are normally native outsiders.

The example creature is a Human, and his type has been changed to *Outsider* (*Augmented Humanoid*)(*Native*). This would suggest that no, Favored Enemy: *Outsider* (*Evil*) would not be used vs. a half-fiend. Similarly, the "Fiendish" template does not even grant the *Outsider* type.

Comment: Always evil... until some author writes a cheesy story about a rebellious half-fiend who wants to be good and heroic. ;)

Comment: @MasonWheeler "**Evil Subtype** - A subtype usually applied only to outsiders native to the evil-aligned Outer Planes. Evil outsiders are also called fiends. Most creatures that have this subtype also have evil alignments; however, if their alignments change, they still retain the subtype..." From [the SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm) since I don't have my books in front of me. Thus, even a reformed Half-Fiend would still be subject to a Ranger's Favored Enemy: _Outsider_ (_Evil_).

Comment: Does the template actually give the subtype according to RAW? What about e.g. the Chaotic subtype for a half-demon?

Comment: @Random832 I can not say by RAW, as I no longer own my books and am thus limited to the SRD. However, a creature can have more than one subtype; a [Succubus](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/demon.htm#succubus) is an _Outsider_ ( _Chaotic, Extraplanar, Evil_ ) creature. IIRC there were better details on this in the late-3.0 Savage Species book.

Comment: @Random832 I acquired a copy from the library, and edited my answer accordingly; a prime example of why the SRD shouldn't be considered a reference, or at least not the only.